# Unable to print data using console.table

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I am using console.table in my program, test.js to display data but with no luck.

```
require('console.table');

var values = [
      ['max', 20],
      ['joe', 30]
];
console.table(['name', 'age'], values);
```

And when I run this app I get nothing on the screen

```
$ node test.js 
$
```

I have already installed console.table

```
$ npm install --save console.table
npm WARN mysqldb@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN mysqldb@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ console.table@0.8.0
updated 1 package in 0.687s

$ node test.js 
$
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, kindly advice.

Comment: Can you tell me the node version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is not of console.table .
Actually console.table does not work on version node 7+

version node 6.11

the output is this

[image]

and in version node 8.0

the output is

[image]

Comment: Opps, current node version on my laptop is 8.2.1

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_table_tabulardata_properties
As per this, console.table should work for node versions after v10.0.0. Lower versions of node js doesnt support this.

Answer (score 5):

Have you install console.table package or not.

If you didn't install then first install using

```
npm install --save console.table
```

Try this

```js
require('console.table')
var values = [
      ['max', 20],
      ['joe', 30]
];
console.table(values);
```

This is my output

[image: Output]

I am trying your script as well and I am getting result

[image: Output]

---

Well for upper version of node.js you need not to install `console.table` if still you install you have to use console.table like as follows.

```
    delete console.table;
    require('console.table');
```

or

```
    require('console.table')({force: true})
```

Comment: For upper version of the node.js I have updated the code please look into that

Answer (score -1):

I have used a frame work called columnify - npm install columnify

```
const columnify = require('columnify');

//Connect to datbase (mycompany) collection
        db.collection('employee').find({}, {projection:{_id:    0}}).toArray((err, allRecords) => {

            //Error checking
            if (err) {
            console.log('Error encontered!!!');
            } else {

            console.log(columnify(allRecords));


                process.exit(0);
            };


        });
```